# How does the computed width different from the specified width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I'm trying to make a new layout when I encountered this behaviour where the computed width is different from the specified width. So now, I'm curious on the way the width is computed in this scenario.

I know I can use `.row-1 { width: calc(100% - 70px); }` so `row-2` will have `70px` width, but I want to know how `width: 100%` works with px width in this case.

I expect the width of `row-2` to be `70px`, but the computed value is somewhere in between `60px - 69px`.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.row-2 {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-1">row 1</div>
      <div class="row row-2">row 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The last sentence may be confusing as to what my inquiry is about. What I want to know is the way the browser computes the width of `row-2` in this scenario. Why is it not `70px` like the specified width?

Comment: your row are flex elements , if i remember it has default flex:0 1 auto. It means : _It makes the flex item inflexible when there is some free space left, but allows it to shrink to its minimum when there is not enough space_

Comment: Yes @Sfili_81, it has a default `flex: 0 1 auto`. But, do you happen to know how `row-2` width is computed to `60px`+ instead of `70px`?

Comment: because row 2 need 60px to show it's content

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to the elements and you will see (100% + 70px > 100% so the elements will shrink equally by the extra 70px )

Answer (score 2):

Instead us `width` use [`flex:1 0 ...`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row-1 {
     flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.row-2 {
     flex: 1 0 70px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-1">row 1</div>
      <div class="row row-2">row 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a good solution. But, I want to know how `row-2` got a width of `60px`+ instead of `70px` in my post.

Comment: Flexbox items have flex-shrink parameter with default of 1. This means that in case your flexbox container don't have enough space its items will shrink.:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-shrink.asp